# How do I read a SQLite file stored in Object Storage from a Python notebook in Spark as a Service all on Bluemix?

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I have a SQLite file in an Object Storage instance on IBM's Bluemix.  I want to access that file from a Python notebook in Spark as a Service.  Right now, the following code does not work:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').\
     options(url='jdbc:sqlite:swift://container.spark/db.sqlite',\
     dbtable='schema.tablename').load()
print df.take(10)
```

The error I get is: *No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite://container.spark/db.sqlite*

I've been looking for documentation for this, but I haven't been able to find it.  Any  help would be much appreciated.  How do I access a SQLite file on Object Storage from Spark as a Service on Bluemix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one parameter to specify in option that is which driver to look for.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').\
     options(url='jdbc:sqlite:Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite',\
     dbtable='employee',driver='org.sqlite.JDBC').load()
```

Add `driver='org.sqlite.JDBC'` and you would note get the driver not found.

But for reading sqlite from Object storage, i don't think that is supported
by org.sqlite.JDBC.
The only three methods allowed are absolute path, relative path from your file system and memory.
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

In below example, i have downloaded sample sqlite database in Bluemix spark service's local disk and then used it.

https://cdsx.ng.bluemix.net/data/notebooks/1fa97ca4-721a-41b2-a958-ee58bc47577b/view?access_token=5f4e48fd292c59949ffc969b048ab849861b0a95ed708d0d679bf65ce2bf1588

Github importable notebook:-
https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/blob/master/sqllite_jdbc.ipynb

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!  I'll try to do this in a similar way.  This may seem trivial, but can you expand on what you did in the '#Download sqlite jdbc and add it as a jar' step?

Comment: Hi Ross...pls ignore that step...I was writing Scala notebook then realized that bluemix already had driver for SQLite and u are looking for Python code...I just updated github repo